# Overlap between two datasets

Tags: r

I am currently working on two sets of data that provide monthly prices for the same financial products between 02/2013 and 09/2018. The two datasets do not have every monthly price for every product, and Dataset 1 has more accurate data than Dataset 2.

I would like to find a way to merge the two datasets to obtain a resulting dataset that has the most accurate data (from Dataset1), and complete this data with available data from Dataset 2.

In addition, I would like to know what pourcentage of the data overlaps between the two datasets.

Let's say these are samples of my two datasets :

```
Dataset 1
 201602     201603     201604                 
1 103.5     102.4      101.6 
2 0         0          104.2              
3 101.6     101.7      102     

Dataset 2
 201602     201603     201604                 
1 0         103.1      102.8 
2 102.3     103.5      104.5              
3 0         101.5      102.3
```

I would like to obtain :

```
Dataset 1
`201602`   `201603`   `201604`                 
1 103.5     102.4      101.6 
2 102.3     103.5      104.2              
3 101.6     101.7      102
```

And an indication that my overlap = 5/9 = 55.6%

I have more than 1000 financial products, so I'm looking for the simplest possible code.

Thank you in advance for you help !

Comment: What do you mean by "overlap" ? How is it calculated ?

Comment: Do your two datasets have exactly the same number of rows and column, corresponding to the same months and products? And does the value `0` indicate missing?

Comment: @MKBakker : My datasets have exactly the same numbers of rows and columns corresponding to the same months and products, yes. And the value `0` does indicate missing

Comment: @RonakShah by "overlap" I mean the pourcentage of data that is present in both datasets, taking under account that `0` means no data. For example, for column `201603`, the data in rows 1 and 3 are present in both datasets, so they overlap.

Comment: @RonakShah however, there is no overlap for column `201602'. Dataset 1 has data for rows 1 and 3 while Dataset 2 doesn't, and Dataset 2 has data for row 2 while Dataset 1 doesn't

Comment: @RomainBerrou I see. I understand you now. I have updated my answer based on your comment to calculate overlap.

Comment: Just a suggestion: try to work with **long** tables instead of **wide** ones, it makes easier almost any data processing you want to do. That's the biggest leap from spreadsheet users, ever.

Comment: @PavoDive thanks for the advice ! Can you tell me why that is ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to give preference to `df1` over `df2` we can copy contents of `df1` to `df3` and replace values of `df1` which has 0 in them with `df2`.

```
df3 <- df1
df3[df3 == 0] <- df2[df3 == 0]

df3
#  201602 201603 201604
#1  103.5  102.4  101.6
#2  102.3  103.5  104.2
#3  101.6  101.7  102.0
```

To calculate overlap, we can compare the non-zero values in both the data

```
mean((df1 != 0) == (df2 != 0)) * 100
#[1] 55.55555556
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(`201602` = c(103.5, 0, 101.6), `201603` = c(102.4, 
0, 101.7), `201604` = c(101.6, 104.2, 102)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))

df2 <- structure(list(`201602` = c(0, 102.3, 0), `201603` = c(103.1, 
103.5, 101.5), `201604` = c(102.8, 104.5, 102.3)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

Comment: The first parts looks good. However, with computing the overlap, you are now calculating for which field both `df1` and `df2` are non-zero. Not whether these non-zero values are equal. For that you could do: `mean((df1==df2) & (df1!=0)) * 100`. In your example data that will be 0% (do check, all values are different), but with other data such as @Romain Berrou provided, it gives the overlapping percentage. If you fix this, then +1 from me.

Comment: @MKBakker I agree but OP's definition of overlap is different (from the comments below their post). `by "overlap" I mean the percentage of data that is present in both datasets, taking under account that 0 means no data` so they want to know the percentage of non-zero fields in both df1 and df2 and that's how you get their expected output of `55.6%`.  Let me know if I have misunderstood something.

Comment: Now that you say it, I guess that was the definition requested. In that case you did exactly what OP asked!

Comment: @MKBakker I think with your formula, the answer would be 11% (1/9), because 103.5 is present in both initial dataset, no?

Comment: Thanks a lot guys ! @RonakShah's formula did it for me, and I now have another useful formula to identify the % of precisely similar data !

Comment: @RomainBerrou MKBakker is also calculating it by position. since 103.5 is not present at same place in both dataframe they do not overlap.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment I mentioned that it's often always a good idea to work with **long** tables instead of **wide** ones. In long tables the information is *tidy*: each row is an observation, and each column is a variable. While wide tables are nicer to spreadsheet users, long tables are easier to work with by using serious analytical tools, like **R**.

I'll use `data.table` package throughout the answer, as it is very fast and convenient:

### Convert your data to data.tables and add an id column

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, id := 1:.N]

setDT(df2)[, id := 1:.N]
```

### Convert wide tables to long ones

```
longdf1 <- melt(df1, id.vars = "id")
longdf2 <- melt(df2, id.vars = "id")
# check what's in longdf1!
```

### Join the tables and create the new variable

```
## I'll do it first in two steps, but you can use chaining and do it straigth away:
# first join the tables:

joinedTable <- longdf1[longdf2, on = .(id, variable)]

# then create the variable:

joinedTable[, newValue := ifelse(value == 0, i.value, value)]

## Alternatively, you can do it in one run:

joinedTable <- longdf1[longdf2, on = .(id, variable)][, newValue := ifelse(value == 0, i.value, value)]
```

`joinedTable` now has the result you want (although it is in a long format).

Why is a long format useful? Try plotting it (this is clearly **not** part of the question, but I think is one of the most relevant parts!):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(longdf1, aes(x = id, y = value, color = variable))+geom_point()
```

Or try to get the average value:

```
longdf1[, mean(value)]
```

(Try to do those two operations on the wide table, the code is much longer and convoluted). In general, operations are easier to perform in long tables.

### converting back to wide

Perhaps you need the data back into wide form, so this would be the code:

```
dcast(joinedTable[, .(id, variable, newValue)], id ~ variable)
```

### Data Used

```
df1 <- structure(list(`201602` = c(103.5, 0, 101.6), `201603` = c(102.4, 
0, 101.7), `201604` = c(101.6, 104.2, 102)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))

df2 <- structure(list(`201602` = c(0, 102.3, 0), `201603` = c(103.1, 
103.5, 101.5), `201604` = c(102.8, 104.5, 102.3)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

## EDIT: I almost forgot the "overlap" calculation:

```
joinedTable[, sum(apply(.SD, 1, function(x) !any(x == 0)))/.N, .SDcols = c("value", "i.value")]
[1] 0.5555556
```

Comment: Thanks for this long answer ! I'll try to apply it ASAP an come back to you !